# How can I use JavaScript to determine the duration of an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have looked into trying to test internet connection to prevent people from being left on a loading screen for too long and I haven't found a good method for this. Is there a way I can figure out how long my loading animation has run for and if it exceeds x amount of seconds/ minutes to display an alert to check the connection? I am familiar with JavaScript and some libraries and open to other languages just want the job done. Thanks! 
 
*P.S.: Below is the code and animation I have as the loading screen and because if it doesn't connect to a jQuery CDN it won't load I want to mitigate time people spend on said screen.*

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.loader').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.page_cover').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.load-txt-cont').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3b404d;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  outline: none;
}

.page_cover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #3b404d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.conet-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 19.2px;
}

.loader {
  width: 115.2px;
  height: 115.2px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4.8px solid #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: load 1.25s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: load 1.25s linear infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: load 1.25s linear infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: load 1.25s linear infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: load 1.25s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes load {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes load {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes load {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Code Cafe | Home</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Playball|Lobster+Two" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Ballet Harmony';
      src: url('ballet_harmony-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('ballet_harmony-webfont.woff') format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page_cover">
    <div class="conet-cont">
      <h2 class="load-txt">Preparing everything for you...</h1>
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<h1>Loaded Content</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: You want to test for network availability?

Comment: @terrymorse I've seen this solution and it doesn't seem to work reliably on all browsers. I was hoping to track something like, how long the element has had the opacity: 1; or display: flex; if at all possible.

Comment: See my updated answer. Since you are trying to load jQuery, you can check for its presence to determine connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request seems to be a test for network connection after a certain time.

Simple network connectivity can be detected with the [Navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) property.

```
let online = navigator.onLine;
```

To use a time delay before informing the user, you can use the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

```
let timeout = setTimeout(myTimeoutHandler, 5000);
```

A very simple example that checks the connection after 5 seconds, showing an alert if there is no connection:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  if (!navigator.onLine) {
    alert('no network connection');
  }
}, 5000);
```

But the question arises on how good is the browser support for `navigator.onLine`?

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=navigator.online), the support is quite good.

[image: browser support for navigator.onLine]

**Update**

The original code is attempting to load jQuery from a CDN, so simply looking for the presence of jQuery will determine connectivity.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'function') {
    alert('jQuery not loaded');
  }
}, 5000);
```

Example to demonstrate.

```js
function testForJquery() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'function') {
      alert('jQuery not loaded');
    } else {
       alert('jQuery is loaded');
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function loadJQuery () {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

```html
<body>
<h4>Test for jQuery</h4>
<button onclick="loadJQuery();">Load jQuery</button><br/>
<button onclick="testForJquery();">Test for jQuery</button><br/>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the solution I've seen but I'd like the solution to be a browser friendly as possible and this doesn't work reliably across most browsers.

Comment: @JordanDunton According to caniuse, the support for `navigator.onLine` is very broad. https://caniuse.com/#search=navigator.online

Comment: I tested the update and there is a major issue...this solution uses jQuery to see if jQuery is not running and if there is no internet then jQuery isn't running to tell me jQuery isn't working. You see the issue.

Comment: @JordanDunton The code provided doesn't use jQuery. It uses vanilla JavaScript to check for the presence of a `window.jQuery` property, which will exist only if jQuery is loaded. See the working code snipped above.

Comment: Sorry, the above solution does work and I've got it set up. One of those, "Well it did work one second, I refreshed and it works" types of things. I'll give this the thumbs up and thanks!

Comment: @JordanDunton Good news, I'm glad you got it working.